# Can I display part of a window on the second device?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, x11

When giving presentations, I use the html/css/js-based `showoff`. It has a presenter mode which shows the notes and the progress in a good way for me. It seems like the idea is that somehow a second browser gets the changes I do in this mode, but that does not work.

Therefore I thought of putting just the part of the presenter mode which displays the current slide (this is a 1024x768 area) on another device, namely the beamer display.

As `X` has such a vast tooling box, I figured this could be possible. The presentation has been given with mirrored displays, which went good enough. What remains is the curiosity if it would have been possible:

```
Can I display part of a window on the second device?
```

I use `xmonad` as window manager normally. If this is supported by another window manager, I could switch just for presentations.

**UPDATE**

I am more interested in the way this could be achieved by `X11` means (or related tools) than just having the presenation run fine. That's just the incident that created my interest in such a solution.

**SECOND UPDATE**

I am still looking for a pure X11-solution, but the problem at hand is of course solved.

Comment: See answer involving `xrandr` here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97005/viewing-a-part-of-the-screen-in-a-window-on-linux/97487

Comment: If this were an answer, I would mark it as the right one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a thing about `showoff`, but I did use [`dzslides`](http://paulrouget.com/dzslides/) in a similar way.  Things to check are:

- Does you window manager support multiple displays? (E.g. after `xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of LVDS1`, does it handle the "other one"?) [XMonad should,](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Frequently_asked_questions#Multi_head_and_workspaces_.28desktops.29), [i3](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#multi_monitor) provides good multihead support, too.
- Your presenter console should control the other window *in normal presentation mode*. **What happens when you open both modes in separate windows?** I.e. when `showoff` says

  ```
  Your ShowOff presentation is now starting up.

  To view it plainly, visit [ #{url} ]

  To run it from presenter view, go to: [ #{url}/presenter ]
  ```

  try opening *both* URLs in two windows.
- If, as I hope it does, the presenter view window controls the plain view one, just move the plain view window to the other monitor (this depends on how your WM handles multiple monitors).  If it doesn't, you could consider [filing an issue](https://github.com/schacon/showoff/issues)...

This *should* be easier than X11 hackery.

Comment: I have no problems with multiple displays, thanks to `xmonad`. Opening both modes in separate windows does not lead to them updating at the same time. At least not in my testing.

Comment: Also, I am more interested in the X11 hackery as the presentation itself is over.

Comment: In current showoff, the presenter-url opens a second window which reflects the state you see in the presenter-mode. This does not satisfy my curiosity, but solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned about [arandr](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/), which allows to visually align your monitors. Nothing is keeping you (well, me, in this case) to overlay the space that is shown on a specific monitor. In theory, one could calculate offsets and positions themselves and use [xrandr](https://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/)-commands directly.

On a sidenote, [showoff](https://puppetlabs.github.io/showoff/) is now maintained by PuppetLabs and has a working presenter-mode like the one sr_ suggested in his answer.